# Checking independence of variables in a Bayesian network

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian-network

I need a little help with Bayesian Networks. Consider given the following network (all variables are binary) and we need to check conditional independence of $A$ and $C$ if $X$ and $Z$ are given.

Any suggestions?

The network is:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some online software that might help you:

[www.causality.org.uk](http://www.causality.org.uk)

Shameless plug aside, you want to be able to say that $A$ and $C$ are $d$-separated by $X$ and $Z$ (because $d$-separation is a good proxy for statistical independance under certain assumptions).

The basic idea is to check the paths (without cycles) ignoring the arrows. So you have two paths

$$(I) \;\;\; A\rightarrow Z \leftarrow Y \leftarrow X \leftarrow C$$
$$(II) \;\;\; A\rightarrow Z \leftarrow B \rightarrow X \leftarrow C$$

The idea then is to check that both paths are blocked by conditioning on $X$ and $Z$. I find this definition easy to work with, a path is blocked if

1. the path contains a chain $P \rightarrow Q \rightarrow R$ or a fork
   $P \leftarrow Q \rightarrow R$ with $Q$ being conditioned, **OR**
2. the path contains a collider $P \rightarrow Q \leftarrow R$ with neither $Q$ *nor any descendant* of $Q$ being conditioned.

The first one *roughly* corresponds to our intuition about common causes, and the second one *roughly* corresponds to our understanding of [Simpson's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox).

The "or" is very important. Because (I) satisfies 1 but not 2. But (II) does not satisfy either. What is happening here is you are (potentially) introducing a correlation between $A$ and $C$ by your conditioning on $X$ and $Z$ via their link to $B$ (Simpson's paradox).

**Note**

Conditioning on *either* $X$ or $Z$ would give you independence, it's just doing both that makes it fail.

Conditioning on $X$ introduces a correlation between $A$ and $B$, which is fine on its own, conditioning on $Z$ introduces a correlation between $B$ and $C$, which is fine on its own. But doing both introduces a correlation between $A$ and $C$ because $A$ is correlated with $B$ and $B$ is correlated with $C$.

Comment: Thanks, it is rather helpful, but I need to show it analytically.

Comment: It has a tutorial part, but the whole d-separation bit is incomplete.

Comment: I will add how to work it out by hand...

Comment: Thanks, I will check carefully.

Comment: @RomanDryndik actually, it seems I haven't uploaded it at all. Sorry :(

Comment: @RomanDryndik Is that more helpful? I can expand it if need be.

Comment: @RomanDryndik to show it analytically you just have to find a suitable probability dist on the graph; knowing that the answer is that they are dependent in general, just make a distribution where they really are dependent to prove it.

Comment: @guy, he was responding to my original answer which was just "I have a website".

Comment: @Lucas thanks. It was helpful, now it is clear. Appreciate.